# AngularJS controller called before jquery document ready callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, document-ready

I have two Angular 1.x controllers and an external open source library with gets initialized on document ready as follows,

```
 $(function () {
    $.support.x = 10;
 });
```

So the ordering in which I load the JS files are
1. Angular framework
2. This external OS library
3. My AngularJS controllers

Once I load the page, the `document.ready(jquery)` of open source library is not getting called first, rather control is going to AngularJS controller constructors first. After the controller execution is complete, then only `document.ready(jquery)` is called.

I have simplified the context here, but I have other javascript files as well before my controllers. The doubts which I have are,

1. Why is the controller getting loaded first ?
2. Is it to do with the ordering of my JS files ?
3. AngularJS loads first irrespective of other `document.ready(jquery)` methods 
   in other JS libraries ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you want to load it before angular?

Comment: Thats an external open source library whose implementation is that way. It has some implementation on load.

Comment: have u tried to load it in angular's .run method

Comment: You mean to say in the angular run method, I need to call whatever is happening in that OS library explicitly. So, I have to edit the OS file as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#automatic-initialization):

> AngularJS initializes automatically upon `DOMContentLoaded` event or
>   when the `angular.js` script is evaluated if at that time
>   `document.readyState` is set to `complete`.

So:

1) I think that's because the angular.js script goes earlier of any `$(document).ready(function(){});` handlers and angularjs starts bootstrapping before this handlers are fired;

2) Yes. Take a look at this two examples (the difference is only in the `angular.js` script placement):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var ctrl = this;
    console.log('ctrl');  
    return ctrl;
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">  
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('doc');
});
</script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
```

and:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var ctrl = this;
    console.log('ctrl');  
    return ctrl;
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">  
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('doc');
});
</script>
```

For the first one the output will be `doc-ctrl`and for the second one `ctrl-doc`.

3) By default it loads as described in the quote. But you can use [manual initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization) to control the process. No matter when the `angular.js` script is included, the order of output will be `doc - stuff.loaded -> do bootstrap - ctrl`

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var ctrl = this;
    console.log('ctrl');  
    return ctrl;
}]);
```

```html
<div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">  
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on('stuff.loaded', function(){
  console.log("stuff.loaded -> do bootstrap");
  //manually bootstrap angularjs app
  angular.element(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('doc');
  //some your stuff here 
  //...
  $(document).trigger('stuff.loaded');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Its pretty clear now. Basically, it boils down to the ordering of the JS files. Lets say, I can't change the ordering, I need to load angular before this external script because of dependency issues. In this case, can I make the document.ready get called before angular loading ?

Comment: @Chaitanya please take a look at updated answer with the last block of code where I tried to show how to do manual initialization. I this case `$(document).ready(function(){})` triggers event that will fire the angularjs initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ng-app? If so you could bootstrap angular manual and remove the ng-app

```
document.ready(function{
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
})
```

Then angular will run after dom is ready
[angular bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Comment: So, I have to remove ng-App and bootstrap it dynamically after document.ready ? Ideally, the ordering of the document.ready will not be maintained by the browser ?

Comment: Yes or you just use the ready callback from jquery and bootstrap it there, then jquery is definitly ready before angular :-)